# строка mas[i, j] = Convert.ToDouble(arr[k++]); вызывает исключение, почему?(Индекс находится вне границ массива)

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace _8лаб
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Read(StreamReader sr, double[,] mas)//считывание с texti.txt
        {
            string str = sr.ReadLine();
            str = str.Replace("\r", " ");
            str = str.Replace("\n", " ");
            string[] arr = str.Split(' ');
            int k = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    **mas[i, j] = Convert.ToDouble(arr[k++]);**
                    Console.Write(mas[i, j] + " ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        static void Print(StreamWriter sW, double[,] x, double[] arr) //вывод в текстовый файл
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < x.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < x.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    sW.Write(x[i, j] + " ");
                }
            }
            sW.WriteLine();
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            string path = "text.txt"; //док для вывода
            StreamWriter sW = new StreamWriter(path); //поток для вывода
            string rep = "texti.txt"; //док для чтения
            StreamReader sR = new StreamReader(rep); //поток для чтения
            double[,] mas = new double[3, 3];
            double[] arr2 = new double[3];
            Read(sR, mas);
            sR.Close();
            Print(sW, mas, arr2);
            sW.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

строка `mas[i, j] = Convert.ToDouble(arr[k++])`; вызывает исключение, почему?

Индекс находится вне границ массива

Comment: очевидно в массиве `arr` элементов меньше чем `k`

Comment: а как так получается, если в в исходном массиве 9 элементов, следовательно, строка тоже состоит из 9 элементов (с пробелами между ними)?

Comment: просто проверь что ты получаешь в arr и какие значения элементов, так же проверь что именно находится в файле из которого ты загружаешь

Comment: Из чего состоит строка - никто не знает - проще всего в отладке посмотреть, ну или печатать каждый элемент :)

Comment: @PashaPash Аделz Идрисова знает

Comment: @Igor это неточно

Answer (score 2):

я поняла в чем ошибка. я пыталась считать весь массив, но написала string str = sr.ReadLine();, а нужно было string str = sr.ReadToEnd();

Comment: Молодец. *(нужно ещё 7 символов...)*

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.GetLength(0) && k < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < mas.GetLength(1) && k < arr.Length; j++)
            {
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]